# Admin forgot password js issue

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, adminhtml, jquery, password

I have Try to solve bellow js issue but not succeed.

i have checked in new magento this file is magento inbuilt merge.

[image]

[image]

Can any one have solution how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Have you enabled `mod_pagespeed` from apache or any module which is merging your js files like that? If yes then disable that and check.

Comment: No. magento forgot password done this inbuilt.

Comment: Thats not possible. Check again. There has to be. Please check the urls in console. All your js file names are appended there. This is not default magento behavior.

Comment: Please check my screen shot which i have taken from fresh magento installation.

Comment: Yes thats why i have said `apache` module. Which is `mod_pagespeed`. Can you do one thing. Go to the `forgot password` page and check the view source and paste it here.

Comment: Ok. Great. what is `x.js` there. Can you try to find out how it gets added from your file system.

Comment: Pleae check view source

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? Maybe it's related to nginx... I have the same issue, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: These scripts are combined this way directly in the template code, mod_pagespeed is not combining them. I have the same errors locally and on our dev sites, however the issue is not present on any of our production sites. Not sure if that will help point to the cause/issue.